# Bootstrap Alternating Layout to stacked in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a basic responsive layout in Bootstrap where the image sits next to the block of text. In the first row the image is on the left, in the second row the image is on the right. This repeats down the page.

The problem: when the user is on a mobile device, the images go full width (as they should), however for any row with the image aligned to the right, it is sitting below the text rather than above (see code below). I understand why this is happening, but am wondering if there is a class within bootstrap that can correct this? It must be fairly common, so what is the suggested best practice here?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row feature">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <img src="url" class="img-responsive"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <h3>subtitle</h3>
            <p>body</p>
          </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row feature">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <h3>subtitle</h3>
            <p>body</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <img src="url" class="img-responsive" />
          </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add any fiddle for that...so i can help you.

Comment: short note: based on bootstrap mobile first concept, you don't need to specify the col-md  style as long you don't want to change the column specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for something like **Nesting Columns** : Here is the doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/qsdH9jr70F

Look this code : and specially at `col-sm-push-6` and `col-sm-pull-6`

**HTML** :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row feature">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <img src="url" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <h1>title</h1>
            <h3>subtitle</h3>
            <p>body</p>
          </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="row feature">      
          <div class="col-sm-push-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">   <!--   HERE   -->
            <img src="url" class="img-responsive">
          </div>   
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-6">   <!--   HERE   -->
            <h1>title</h1>
            <h3>subtitle</h3>
            <p>body</p>
          </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks TheLittlePig - push and pull were exactly what i was looking for.