# Using Bootstrap push and pull

Tags: html, push, pull, hubspot

I've searched around and found this thread: [Bootstrap Alternating Layout to stacked in mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541031/bootstrap-alternating-layout-to-stacked-in-mobile)

However, when I add push and pull to my code I get the pushing and pulling occurring even in full desktop view.

For example:

```
<section class="block block--2">

<div class="container">

    <div class="row padbot20">
        <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <center>
                 <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-address-book"></i>
             </center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="heading padbot20">
                <h3 class="black_txt">
                    {% text "section_2_row_1_heading", overrideable=True, value="Supplier Management", label="Section 2 Row 1 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row-paragraph">
                 {% rich_text "section_2_row_1_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>With Volo, you’ll can keep all your key supplier information up to date so you know exactly where you are. Monitor the prices you’re paying for your stock, use automated data feeds to increase productivity, or use drop-shippers to do the product storage and delivery for you – the choice is yours.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 1 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
        <div class=" col-md-8 ">
            <div class="heading padbot20">
                <h3 class="black_txt">
                    {% text "section_2_row_2_heading", overrideable=True, value="Inventory & Stock Control ", label="Section 2 Row 2 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row-paragraph">
                 {% rich_text "section_2_row_2_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>Control your physical and virtual inventory data across all your sales channels with Volo, from single custom items through to managing millions of SKUs and variations. We’ve made it simple: one central location for storing all the information needed for the different channels. Sell items on one channel and we’ll automatically update the rest.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 2 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 center">
             <center>
                 <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-cubes"></i>
             </center>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
        <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <center>
                 <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-sitemap"></i>
             </center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="heading padbot20">
                <h3 class="black_txt">
                    {% text "section_2_row_3_heading", overrideable=True, value="Multichannel Management", label="Section 2 Row 3 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row-paragraph">
                 {% rich_text "section_2_row_3_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>Selling successfully is about being in the right places, responding quickly and capitalizing on the opportunities. We’ll enable you to reach new markets, new audiences, and new sales targets. Volo gives you resilience across all your channels</p>", label="Section 2 Row 3 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="heading padbot20">
                <h3 class="black_txt">
                    {% text "section_2_row_4_heading", overrideable=True, value="Order Management", label="Section 2 Row 4 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row-paragraph">
                 {% rich_text "section_2_row_4_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>At Volo, our approach is to help bring together all your sales information into a single, coherent view so you can streamline your processes. From matching orders to payments quickly, through to shipping list for packing, manifests for shipments, and invoice and delivery documentation.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 4 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <center>
                 <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-credit-card"></i>
             </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
        <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <center>
                 <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-truck"></i>
             </center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="heading padbot20">
                <h3 class="black_txt">
                    {% text "section_2_row_5_heading", overrideable=True, value="Shipping", label="Section 2 Row 5 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row-paragraph">
                 {% rich_text "section_2_row5_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>We can help you reduce time and costs by implementing a completely integrated fulfillment process. You’ll be able to connect your carriers, shipping aggregators and consolidators into one system, giving you effective and efficient control.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 5 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div></section>
```

However, when I add push and pull, I get a massive gap appearing on the desktop version and the push and pulling still applied, despite adding "col-xs-push-12" and "col-xs-pull-12" to the code example (and screenshot)-

Screenshot:
Code:

```
        <section class="block block--2">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row padbot20">
                <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <center>
                         <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-address-book"></i>
                     </center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="heading padbot20">
                        <h3 class="black_txt">
                            {% text "section_2_row_1_heading", overrideable=True, value="Supplier Management", label="Section 2 Row 1 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-paragraph">
                         {% rich_text "section_2_row_1_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>With Volo, you’ll can keep all your key supplier information up to date so you know exactly where you are. Monitor the prices you’re paying for your stock, use automated data feeds to increase productivity, or use drop-shippers to do the product storage and delivery for you – the choice is yours.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 1 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-push-12 col-xs-push-12">
                    <div class="heading padbot20">
                        <h3 class="black_txt">
                            {% text "section_2_row_2_heading", overrideable=True, value="Inventory & Stock Control ", label="Section 2 Row 2 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-paragraph">
                         {% rich_text "section_2_row_2_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>Control your physical and virtual inventory data across all your sales channels with Volo, from single custom items through to managing millions of SKUs and variations. We’ve made it simple: one central location for storing all the information needed for the different channels. Sell items on one channel and we’ll automatically update the rest.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 2 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-pull-12 col-xs-pull-12">
                     <center>
                         <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-cubes"></i>
                     </center>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
                <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <center>
                         <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-sitemap"></i>
                     </center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="heading padbot20">
                        <h3 class="black_txt">
                            {% text "section_2_row_3_heading", overrideable=True, value="Multichannel Management", label="Section 2 Row 3 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-paragraph">
                         {% rich_text "section_2_row_3_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>Selling successfully is about being in the right places, responding quickly and capitalizing on the opportunities. We’ll enable you to reach new markets, new audiences, and new sales targets. Volo gives you resilience across all your channels</p>", label="Section 2 Row 3 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="heading padbot20">
                        <h3 class="black_txt">
                            {% text "section_2_row_4_heading", overrideable=True, value="Order Management", label="Section 2 Row 4 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-paragraph">
                         {% rich_text "section_2_row_4_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>At Volo, our approach is to help bring together all your sales information into a single, coherent view so you can streamline your processes. From matching orders to payments quickly, through to shipping list for packing, manifests for shipments, and invoice and delivery documentation.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 4 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <center>
                         <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-credit-card"></i>
                     </center>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
                <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <center>
                         <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-truck"></i>
                     </center>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="heading padbot20">
                        <h3 class="black_txt">
                            {% text "section_2_row_5_heading", overrideable=True, value="Shipping", label="Section 2 Row 5 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-paragraph">
                         {% rich_text "section_2_row5_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>We can help you reduce time and costs by implementing a completely integrated fulfillment process. You’ll be able to connect your carriers, shipping aggregators and consolidators into one system, giving you effective and efficient control.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 5 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row padtop20 padbot20">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="heading padbot20">
                        <h3 class="black_txt">
                            {% text "section_2_row_6_heading", overrideable=True, value="Reporting & Analytics", label="Section 2 Row 6 Heading", no_wrapper=True %}
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-paragraph">
                         {% rich_text "section_2_row_6_content", overrideable=True, value="<p>Volo reporting & analytics turns your performance data into information, giving you the knowledge and confidence to make quick decisions that positively impact all the things you measure your success by: revenues, profits and cash flow.</p>", label="Section 2 Row 6 Content", no_wrapper=True %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 center col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <center>
                         <i class="fa_black_icon fa fontawesome-icon fa-pie-chart"></i>
                     </center>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>

    </section>
```

But then this happens:
https://gyazo.com/7a39f8711b274eda998d48eae5278634

What am I doing wrong?

Any advice would be appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain your code like below.

About -- Look and Feel sho

Your code structure is looks like you need **2 column in single row**.

Design should be **`col-md-4`** and **`col-md-8`** in desktop version.

And in mobile and tablet device design should be look like in dropped column like **`col-sm-12`**.

.

Create you code structure like below, and make sure about maintenance code constancy like below.

```
<section class="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-sm-12">Icon</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-12">Details will be here.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">Icon</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">Details will be here.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-sm-12">Icon</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-12">Details will be here.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">Icon</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">Details will be here.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Hope it helps you.. Cheers :)